# How to Give Painting of Baby Lord Krishna

Tags: krishna, idols

How give my own painting of Baby Lord Krishna while respecting Hindu sentiments.

Is mailing allowed, or should I deliver personally?

Specifically, what does Hinduism say about transporting/gifting images/idols of Deities?

Comment: I don't think their's any such rule about sending paintings of God through USPS. Sentiments would most probably not be hurt.

Comment: Should be respectful, must be with clean stuff, no nonveg near to it, better to be on top, no feet should touch it, keep it unbroken place. These are some of them I can think of.

Comment: I like your idea of presenting a God's painting which should not be stopped because of your lack of knowledge so sent the above comment 

Comment: @paṇḍyā I updated question, please un-hold

Comment: To make this on-topic, you need to remove all your personal details, i.e., your first two statements. Also, 'USPS' from the title. Or just change the title to: Is shipping a painting of Lord Krishna allowed? If you make these changes, users can vote to re-open.

Comment: Ok @sv please reopen

Comment: Ok, looks better. I cast my reopen vote, you need 3 more votes.

Comment: I upvoted it. Nice question.